# How to format custom time in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have tried `moment.time(column.start_time).format("hh:mm A")` but it give me error.

I have custom time field value is "15:30:00" want to format like "03:30 PM".

Comment: What type of your `column.start_time`? Date or string?

Comment: Why not use `moment(column.start_time).format("hh:mm A")` - refer to http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 76):

You need to add a format string into the `moment` function because your date is not a valid ISO date.

```js
var time = "15:30:00";
var formatted = moment(time, "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A");
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

I will include one more additional information:

**When you use hh:mm A**

```
var time = "15:30:00";
var formatted = moment(time, "HH:mm").format("hh:mm A");
console.log(formatted); 
//it will return 03:30 PM
```

**And when you use LT**

```
var time = "15:30:00";
var formatted = moment(time, "HH:mm:ss").format("LT");
console.log(formatted); 
//it will return 3:30 PM
```

The difference between one and another is just a 0 before the first number when it is lower then 10. I am working with date time picker and then I understood why it was not binding in my combo box.

More details in:
https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/#localized-formats

I hope it can help